# Java 8: Generic type inference improvements

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, java-8

With [JEP 101: Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101), this

```
final List<Boolean> bools = Arrays.asList(true,false, true);
final List<Character> string = bools.stream()
        .<Character>map(x -> x ? 'X' : 'O')
        .collect(Collectors.<Character>toList());
```

should be reducable to

```
    final List<Boolean> bools = Arrays.asList(true, false, true);
    final List<Character> string = bools.stream()
            .map(x -> x ? 'X' : 'O')
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in Java 8, but the latter does not compile:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Character>`

Have I got it wrong? 
Or am I ahead of my tools?

I am using [JDK 8 build b120](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) together with [eclipse-SDK-4.3.1-win32-x86_64-efx-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.zip](http://downloads.efxclipse.org/eclipse-java8/2013-06-30/).

Comment: Working here : http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52ac7495e4b01939e475a24b

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty useful!

Comment: Remember, Eclipse does not use the JDK compiler so their snapshot builds may still be catching up with the final specification.

Comment: Try compiling with javac

Comment: It looks like this is still on the [schedule of the JDT team](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this issue is fixed now with the latest JDT snapshot implementing the desired proposal.

Answer (score 2):

It just works fine under IntelliJ Idea 13 which seems ahead of Eclipse for Java8 support.
So I guess you just have to wait until Eclipse will be able to compile this.

Comment: Looks like it is a long wait, because I still get an error almost exactly like this on the 4.4.1 release a whole year later. lol

Answer (score 0):

The example is accepted by every Eclipse release since the release of Java 8.

(Releases greater or equal P20140317-1600).