# Java 1.8 Upgrade Mockito matchers compilation error

Tags: java, mockito

This is an Issue which I am having while Upgrading my REST project from 1.7 to 1.8

The test cases seem to show compilation errors after the upgrade

This is the Old code which used to work

```
when(mockBuilder.post(any(Class.class), anyObject()))
        .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

where the post method in my builder is

```
@Override
    public <T> T post(Class<T> c, Object requestEntity) {
        return response();
    }
```

Now after the Upgrade my  mock test case shows a compilation failure 
I have java 1.8 and mockito 1.9

Seems like the compiler is unable to find a method with matching arguments

I have tried using other mockito mathcers like any(),isA() and Eq()
None of them seems to works,Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What compilation errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try just...

```
when(mockBuilder.post(any(), anyObject()))
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

There have been some changes to Java 8 generics, for example [Java 8: Generic type inference improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584836/java-8-generic-type-inference-improvements)